# How to convert multiple fasta lines in a matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, bioinformatics

I have a file (txt or fasta) like this. Each sequence is located only in a single line.

```
    >Line1
    ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANAGCTAGANCACGATAGAGAGAGACTATAGC
    >Line2
    ATTGCGCTANANAGCTANANCGATAGANCACGAAAGAGATAGACTATAGC
    >Line3
    ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANGGCTAGANCNCGAAAGNGATAGACTATAGC
    >Line4
    ATTGCGCTANANAGCTANANGGATAGANCACGAGAGAGATAGACTATAGC
    >Line5
    ATTGCGCTANANAGCTANANCGATAGANCACGATNGAGATAGACTATAGC
```

I have to get a matrix in which each position correspond to each of the letters (nucleotides) of the sequences. In this case a matrix of (5x50). 
I've been dealing with numpy methods. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with DNA sequence data in python, I would recommend using the [Biopython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html) library.  You can install it with `pip install biopython`.

Here is how you would achieve your desired result:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import os
import numpy as np

pathToFile = os.path.join("C:\\","Users","Kevin","Desktop","test.fasta")  #windows machine

allSeqs = []
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(pathToFile, """fasta"""):
        allSeqs.append(seq_record.seq)

seqMat = np.array(allSeqs)
```

But in the for loop, each `seq_record.seq` is a [`Seq`](http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq) object, giving you the flexibility to perform operations on them.

```
In [5]: seqMat.shape
Out[5]: (5L, 50L)
```

You can slice your `seqMat` array however you like.

```
In [6]: seqMat[0]
Out[6]: array(['A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A',
       'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'G',
       'A', 'N', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'G', 'A',
       'G', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Highly recommend checking out the tutorial though!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this short bit of code helps. You basically need to split the string into a character array. After that you just put everything into a matrix.

```
Line1 = "ATGC"
Line2 = "GCTA"
Matr1 = np.matrix([n for n in Line1], [n for n in Line2])
```

`Matr1[0,0]` will return the first element in your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving the matrix is to read the content of the file and converting it into a list where each element of the list is the sequence present in each line.And then you can access your matrix as a 2D Data Structure.
Ex: [ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANAGCTAGANCACGATAGAGAGAGACTATAGC, ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANAGCTAGANCACGATAGAGAGAGACTATAGC, ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANAGCTAGANCACGATAGAGAGAGACTATAGC, ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANAGCTAGANCACGATAGAGAGAGACTATAGC, ATCGCGCTANANAGCTANANAGCTAGANCACGATAGAGAGAGACTATAGC]

```
filePath = "file path containing the sequence"
```

List that store the sequence as a matrix

```
listFasta =list ((open(filePath).read()).split("\n"))
for seq in listFasta:
    for charac in seq:
        print charac
```

Another way to access each element of your matrix

```
for seq in range(len(listFasta)):
    for ch in range(len(listFasta[seq])):
        print listFasta[seq][ch]
```